# Error creating bean with name Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to using Spring Boot. I have already got the user registration form and API working fine and successfully added the records into the database. After completing the login API I ran into the problem with the attached error below. I have attached what I have tried below.
I want to display if the login was successful. Displayed as a JSON format it looks like this, I need help, please help me to correct the code below

```
{
  status = "true"'
  message = "login success"
}
```

Full Error

```
ework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeIMPL': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepo' defined in com.example.Registation.Repo.EmployeeRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.example.Registation.Entity.Employee com.example.Registation.Repo.EmployeeRepo.findByUsernamePassword(java.lang.String,java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.Registation.Entity.Employee com.example.Registation.Repo.EmployeeRepo.findByUsernamePassword(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)! No property 'usernamePassword' found for type 'Employee'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.Registation.Entity.Employee com.example.Registation.Repo.EmployeeRepo.findByUsernamePassword(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)! No property 'usernamePassword' found for type 'Employee'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListabl
```

**LoginController**

```
  @PostMapping(path = "/login")
    public String saveEmployee(@RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO)
    {
        String name = employeeService.loginEmployee(loginDTO);
       return "success";
    }
```

LoginDTO.java

```
public class LoginDTO {
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public LoginDTO() {
    }

    public LoginDTO(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LoginDTO{" +
                "email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Employee.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name="employee_id", length = 45)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int employeeid;

    @Column(name="employee_name", length = 255)
    private String employeename;

    @Column(name="email", length = 255)
    private String email;

    @Column(name="password", length = 255)
    private String password;


    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(int employeeid, String employeename, String email, String password) {
        this.employeeid = employeeid;
        this.employeename = employeename;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }


    public int getEmployeeid() {
        return employeeid;
    }

    public void setEmployeeid(int employeeid) {
        this.employeeid = employeeid;
    }

    public String getEmployeename() {
        return employeename;
    }

    public void setEmployeename(String employeename) {
        this.employeename = employeename;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "employeeid=" + employeeid +
                ", employeename='" + employeename + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Repo

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee,Integer> {


      public  Employee findByUsernamePassword(String username, String password);


}
```

EmployeeService.java

```
public interface EmployeeService {
    String addEmployee(EmployeeDTO employeeDTO);

    String loginEmployee(LoginDTO loginDTO);
}
```

EmployeeIMPL.java

```
public String loginEmployee(LoginDTO loginDTO) {
  Employee employee = employeeRepo.findByUsernamePassword(loginDTO.getEmail(),loginDTO.getPassword());

  if(employee == null)
  {
      return "Employee ID Not Found";
  }
  else
  {
      return "Logged In";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. `No property 'usernamePassword' found for type 'Employee'`

It expect `usernamePassword` field inside `Employee`, but in your `Employee.java` you have email and password?

You might want to change `findByUsernamePassword(String username, String password);` to:

```java
public  Employee findOneByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
```

#### Or

Create a `String username` field in `Employee.java` with its getters and setters. Then change the repository method to

```java
public  Employee findOneByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
```

Read this for more details https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: now error go away.but if i test through api login. if i type wrong user and password also display the message success why is that

Comment: You might want to check your authentication logic.

Comment: in controller we have to check so i don't know how to check